# Include bcm2853 lib on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c#, dll, raspberry-pi, spi

I want to start SPI communication with C# on my Raspberry.
The bcm2835 lib supports the needed commands like:

- `bcm2835_spi_begin()`
- `bcm2835_spi_end()`
- etc.

In C you have to `#include < bcm2835.h >` but in C# `using bcm2835;` does not work.

RaspberryPiDotNet is installed and the bcm2835 library aswell.

The GPIO Pins can be controlled with the `GPIOMem` command which uses the bcm2835 library.

How can C# use the SPI commands of bcm2835 ? Everything on the net is for C or C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## How to get SPI working with C# on the Raspberry Pi

Here is a complete Tutorial how to get it to work:

1. Install Mono:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install mono-complete
   ```
2. Install RaspberryPiDotNet:

   ```
   mkdir gpio_csharp
   git clone git://github.com/cypherkey/RaspberryPi.Net.git
   cd RaspberryPi.Net/RaspberryPiDotNet
   xbuild RaspberryPiDotNet.csproj
   cp bin/Debug/RaspberryPiDotNet.dll /home/pi/gpio_csharp/
   ```
3. Install bcm2835 library:

   ```
   wget http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/bcm2835/bcm2835-1.36.tar.gz
   tar -zxf bcm2835-1.36.tar.gz
   cd bcm2835-1.36
   ./configure
   make
   sudo make check
   sudo make install
   cd src
   cc - shared bcm2835.o -o libbcm2835.so
   cp libbcm2835.so /home/pi/gpio_csharp/
   ```
4. Delete unused files and folders:  
   With this command you can delete the created folders and files but do not delete the "gpio_csharp":

   ```
   rm -r <folder>
   rm <file>
   ```
5. Create a C# script:

   ```
   nano /home/pi/gpio_csharp/xxxxx.cs   //xxxxx is your filename
   CTRL + X     //For exit and save script
   ```
6. Add SPI commands in the script: 
   (Add this in the "class" space of the programm)

   ```
   [DllImport("libbcm2835.so", EntryPoint = "bcm2835_spi_begin")]
   static extern void spi_begin();

   [DllImport("libbcm2835.so", EntryPoint = "bcm2835_spi_end")]
   static extern void spi_end();

   [DllImport("libbcm2835.so", EntryPoint = "bcm2835_spi_transfer")]
   static extern byte spi_transfer(byte val);

   [DllImport("libbcm2835.so", EntryPoint = "bcm2835_spi_chipSelect")]
   static extern byte spi_chipSelect(GPIOPins pin);

   [DllImport("libbcm2835.so", EntryPoint = "bcm2835_spi_setClockDivider")]
   static extern byte spi_setClockDivider(int val);

   [DllImport("libbcm2835.so", EntryPoint = "bcm2835_spi_setDataMode")]
   static extern byte spi_setDataMode(int val);

   [DllImport("libbcm2835.so", EntryPoint = "bcm2835_spi_setChipSelectPolarity")]
   static extern byte spi_setChipSelectPolarity(GPIOPins pin, bool activeHigh);
   ```
7. Use commands in your code:
   Now you can use the following commands to use SPI. Example is down the page.

   ```
    spi_begin();
    spi_end();
    spi_transfer();
    spi_chipSelect();
    spi_setClockDivider();
    spi_setDataMode();
    spi_setChipSelectPolarity();
   ```

   **Example:**

   ```
       //SPI Try
       spi_setClockDivider(128);
       spi_setDataMode(0);
       spi_chipSelect(cs);
       spi_setChipSelectPolarity(cs, false);
       spi_begin();
       spi_transfer(0xAA);
       spi_end();
   ```

Comment: Thanks so much for the tutorial! When compiling libbcm2835 I was lost because I didn't know the step
cc - shared bcm2835.o -o libbcm2835.so

Comment: Your code is `cc - shared bcm2835.o -o libbcm2835.so`, shouldn't it be `cc -shared bcm2835.o -o libbcm2835.so` (no space before `shared`)?